# How to externalise HttpSession from WildFly to Redis? (W/O Spring Session)

Tags: java, redis, wildfly, infinispan

## Introduction

So, I'm currently working with some older Java EE applications, applications which are very much stateful, however, with recent changes, there's a need for these applications to become stateless. Rather than spend an insane amount of time refactoring the code, I thought it best to seek an alternative solution, perhaps something via configuration.

**Note:** Now please bear with me, if I lack knowledge in any given topic that I'm going to cover in this question, please feel free to educate me. I know there are some areas where I could easily improve with, i.e. DevOps, it's hardly my strongest topic.

---

## The Problem

I've seen many solutions that makes use of Spring, or more precisely Spring Session & that approach looks awesome, very clean, clear & straightforward. However, as initially stated, rather than refactor loads of our existing code, or any for that matter, I was hoping to find an alternative solution.

My current progress is still investigating time into conducting research, mostly because I'm still to discover anything that appears solid/fool proof. At best, [this](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-cachestore-redis) is the best thing I've found so far, the only problem is, prior to this issue, I didn't even know what Infinispan was, so I'm hardly an expert at configuring Infinispan with WildFly.

I've also stumbled across [this](https://developer.jboss.org/message/972488#972488) comment, which looks potentially somewhat promising, but sadly I'm personally unsure of how I could utilise this, again, a lack of education on this topic.

---

## Finally

I'd like to thank anyone that could help me in advance, I'm not asking for someone to hand me a solution, rather point me in the right direction(s). I'd like to actually educate myself on this topic, from what I've read so far, I've already learned quite a bit, but I'm still far from an expert on this subject. I also know that I also need to improve my abilities with regards to configuring WildFly/JBoss.

**P.S.** Any form of reading material would be amazing, free or not.

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? I have a similar problem of trying to externalise the httpSession to Redis. Curious to hear how you solved it.

Comment: Hey @Phuthib, long story short no, I ended up going down an SOA route with developing web applications & one key thing that I did was convert from traditional sessions to using JWT's.

Comment: @Phuthib No worries dude, I'm sorry I couldn't be more of help. We accepted the facts & just did a lot of refactoring. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WildFly does not do this. You can however externalize to an Infinispan Server cluster (disclosure: I work on Infinispan). Documentation for the product counterparts (EAP and JDG) is available here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_data_grid/7.2/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/externalize_sessions#externalize_http_session_from_jboss_eap_to_jboss_data_grid

Comment: Hey @TristanTarrant thank you for your input, having done my research so far, I thought that was the case. Unfortunately, with this specific project my team is looking to strictly externalise it to Redis, but again, thank you very much for your input.